# Python Pandas Exception Occurred "example" when Executed Pandas operation in function method,simple function worked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a strange issue and try to explain this here.

Look at this code,Here "df" is pandas dataframe with date as index and open,high,low,close,volume  as columns.

**calc(df)** is the function i am calling to calculate the logic and calling the ematv() inside the get_update() function.

1.In the below code when i run

df = ematv(df.fillna(0),13)

no errors seen,This is calculating EMA based on 'close'

> 2.The same function called from get_update() ,df=ematv(df['example'].fillna(0),lengthema,name='example') when i use to calculate ema where i send 'example' column as data.Here i get the error.
>   **exception occurred 'example'**

What is wrong that i am doing ,This may be a good lesson for me to learn.
Few of the warning i have got given below.

```
def ematv(df,period,name='close'):#closely matching except the decimal
    newcol ='ema'+str(period)+name
    df[newcol] = df[name].ewm(span=period,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    return df


def get_update(df, length=None,threshold = None,lengthema=None):
    if length is None:
        length = 14
        lengthema=13
        column_name = 't1'
    else:
        length = int(length)
        lengthema=int(lengthema)
        column_name = 'ti_{}'.format(length)

    df['example']=TA.test(df)//example column with value added
    df=ematv(df['example'].fillna(0),lengthema,name='example')
    return df


def calc(df):
    df = ematv(df.fillna(0),13)
    df  = get_update(df.fillna(0), length=20,threshold =0,lengthema=13)
    return df

calc(df)
```

some Warning i get:

> pydevd_resolver.py:166: FutureWarning: Series.base is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version   attr = getattr(var, n)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:166: FutureWarning: Series.data is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version   attr = getattr(var, n)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:166: FutureWarning: Series.flags is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version   attr = getattr(var, n)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:166: FutureWarning: Series.itemsize is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version   attr = getattr(var, n)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:166: FutureWarning: Series.strides is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version   attr = getattr(var, n)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:71: FutureWarning: Series.flags is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version   return getattr(var, attribute)
>   pydevd_resolver.py:71: FutureWarning: Series.strides is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version   return getattr(var, attribute)

edit 1: 
Tried changing the code with this edit.

```
def ematv(dff:DataFrame,period,name='close')-> Series:#closely matching except the decimal
    newcol ='ema'+str(period)+name
    dff[newcol] = dff[name].ewm(span=period,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    return dff
```

here now the ema is calculated but i am getting this error
**exception occured Wrong number of items passed 34, placement implies 1**

Comment: well you are calling df = ematv(df.fillna(0),13) in one place and     df=ematv(df['example'].fillna(0),lengthema,name='example'), maybe I am missing something but I believe you are issuing 2 different calls thats why they behave differently

Comment: Both are differrent instances , Once is calculating ema with "close" that is the first instance and the second one is calculating ema where the "example'' column is input. Why it is failing in the second instance then.  Please check the warning given ;exception occurred ,i am not getting any other error.

Comment: can you add the full stack trace of the exception, seems to be the key to this mistery:
exception occurred 'example' .....

Comment: Line `df['example']=TA.test(df)//example column with value added` is not valid Python in `get_update`. Is there a missing # ? Where ? What is TA ?

Comment: @gaFF TA is an import from Finta,Any class instance you can use to check this. https://github.com/peerchemist/finta

Comment: Yes but still line `df['example']=TA.test(df)//example column with value added` is not valid Python in `get_update`. Is there a missing # ? Where ?

Answer (score 0):

how this is solving the issue i am not very sure ,This solved the problem. adding this `df['examples']=''` solves the problem before calling the

> df['examples']=ematv

```
def ematv(dff,period,name='close'):#closely matching except the decimal
    newcol ='ema'+str(period)+name
    dff[newcol] = dff[name].ewm(span=period,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
    return dff[newcol]


def get_update(df, length=None,threshold = None,lengthema=None):
    if length is None:
        length = 14
        lengthema=13
        column_name = 't1'
    else:
        length = int(length)
        lengthema=int(lengthema)
        column_name = 'ti_{}'.format(length)

    df['example']=TA.test(df)//example column with value added
    df['examples']=''
    df['examples']=ematv(df['example'].fillna(0),lengthema,name='example')
    return df


def calc(df):
    df = ematv(df.fillna(0),13)
    df  = get_update(df.fillna(0), length=20,threshold =0,lengthema=13)
    return df

calc(df)
```